# How to get noun phrase with multiple words inside it using Stanford NLP Tregex?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to efficently extract NP using condition with multiple words. This is my current code:

```
public static List<Tree> getNounPhrasesWithMultipleKeywords(Annotation doc,
        List<String> tags) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean firstWord = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
        String word = tags.get(i);
        String[] splitted = word.split(" ");
        for (String splitWord : splitted) {
            if (!firstWord) {
                sb.append(" &");
            }
            sb.append(" << " + splitWord);
            firstWord = false;
        }

    }
    // sb.append(")");

    TregexPattern pattern = TregexPattern.compile("NP < (__"
            + sb.toString() + ")");

    return getTreeWithPattern(doc, pattern);
}
```

Now, lets say that input phrase has got this tree:

```
(ROOT (S (NP (ADJP (RB Poorly) (VBN controlled)) (NN asthma)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (JJ vicious) (NN disease))) (. .)))
```

I want to get only those NP, which contains tags specified in function argument, e.g. for input ["controlled", "asthma"] it should return

```
(NP (ADJP (RB Poorly) (VBN controlled)) (NN asthma))
```

But when input is ["injection", "controlled", "asthma"] it should return nothing.

As you can see, if one of input strings is "multiple words", then program splits it into words. I think that there should be better solution for it, but I don't know how it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to tweak your pattern a little bit.  You didn't really give a complete specification of what you wanted, but from what I could tell `["controlled", "asthma"]` should result in a pattern like `(NP << (controlled .. asthma ))`, which means "Noun Phrase containing 'controlled' followed by 'asthma'".  I'm not sure exactly how you want "phrases" to work; Do you want `["controlled asthma"]` to mean "'controlled' followed immediately by 'asthma'", i.e. `(NP << (controlled . asthma))`?

Here's a new version of your function that creates these patterns:

```
  public static List<Tree> getNounPhrasesWithMultipleKeywords(Annotation doc,
                                                              List<String> tags) {
    List<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
      String word = tags.get(i);
      String[] splitted = word.split(" ");
      phrases.add(join(" . ", Arrays.asList(splitted)));
    }
    String pattern_str = join(" .. ", phrases);
    TregexPattern pattern = TregexPattern.compile(
      "NP << (" + pattern_str + ")");
    return getTreeWithPattern(doc, pattern);
  }

  // In Java 8 use String.join.
  public static String join(String sep, Collection<String> strs) {
    System.out.println(strs);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String s : strs) {
      if (!first) {
        sb.append(sep);
      }
      sb.append(s);
      first = false;
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

This function gives the output you specified in your examples.